# C++ basic integer confusion

Tags: c++, variables

I simply have the line as follows:

```
   int player = 1, i, choice;
```

My question is, what is assigned to i and what is assigned to choice? I was always taught that a variable could not be assigned to multiple values.

Comment: This is not comma operator at work here, people. And this is not a dupe of that question. &%$#!"$#"!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is equivalent to saying

```
int player = 1;
int i;
int choice;
```

You are *not* assigning `1`, `i`, and `choice` into the integer variable `player`.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is assigned anywhere in this -- it's doing initialization not assignment.

`player` is obviously initialized to 1.

If this definition is at namespace scope so `i` and `choice` have static storage duration, then they will be zero-initialized.

If this definition is local to a function, `i` and `choice` will be default-initialized, which (in the case of `int`) means they aren't given a predictable value.

If this definition is inside a class, then `i` and `choice` can be initialized by a constructor. A constructor generated by the compiler will default-initialize them.

Answer (score 1):

They (`i` and `choice`) have unspecified values. They can be pretty much any value, really. Unless you explicitly set them to a value, they are given some "junk" value (typically whatever is already in that memory location that they've been assigned).

You're not assigning to `player` multiple times. You're creating 3 variables, and assigned `1` to `player`. It's the same as if you had written:

```
int player = 1;
int i;
int choice;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of this as:

```
int player = 1;
int i;
int choice;
```

In c++ you are allowed to declare multiple of the same data type on the same line, like

```
char c1, c2, c3;
```

and it is also accepted to give one of these a value in their declaration, like what your line is doing.  So as simonc said, there will be no value in i or choice.

Comment: In c++ you are allowed to declare multiple of the same data type on the same line, like. You are also in c

Comment: @Zaibis: Yes, you are also in C, but according to the tags, the question is only about C++.

Comment: but as you specially mention "c++" it sounds as it would be else where not allowed, if you are refering to "its tagged as c++" just dont mention it explicitly ;P

Comment: I'm mentioning C++ so that people don't assume that this is common in every programming language.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is *definition & initialization, definition, definition*;

```
int player = 1;
int i;// = most probably 'random' trash from heap/stack memory
int choice;// = most probably 'random' trash from heap/stack memory
```

Comment: ...and in this case, all the declarations are also definitions.

Comment: You're right... One would use 'extern' to only declare such an int or whatever. I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

i and choice aren't defined. What happens is, you are saying:
I want to declare player as int and asign 1 to it then a sequens interupt sign(,), says the type specifier has reference to the next sequenz. Means also to declare i and choice as int (but without asigning anythign)

Comment: I've never been so confused!

Comment: I don't think `,` means "sequence interrupt" in this context.

Comment: @ Etienne de Martel exactly thats what a ',' does mean in the standard. And a sequence is finished, at the end of an full expression, so a single declaration is a sequence, so exactly thats what the ',' does, it interupts the sequence!